# How Would I have a button unique add a row to a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I'm wondering how I would add a unique(changing one does't change all of them) row to a `JTable` with a `JButton`

```
final DefaultTableModel mod = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable t = new JTable(mod);
mod.addColumn{"        "};
mod.addColumn{"        "};
JButton b = new JButton
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 //How would I make tf unique by producing a different variable every row if changed
 final JTextField tf = new JTextField();
 final Object[] ro = {"UNIQUE ROW", tf};
 mode.addRow(ro);
 }):
 tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   //s change to an other variable every row added
   String s = tf.getText();
 }):
```

Comment: If this were my problem and I were seeking help here, I'd take a little time to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since I'd know that this would be the best and quickest way to get folks to fully understand my problem and then help me.

Comment: Also, you seem to be trying to add a JTextField component to a table model's row, and I don't think that you really want to do that since JTable's don't display components per se but rather rendered "copies" of components. And while the same column of each row may share the same "rendered" component, the displayed content is different precisely because the model's data is different. Better for you to more fully describe what you're trying to achieve, and yes, create and post your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem close, but you don't want to add JTextField's to a table row. Instead add the data it holds. For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class UniqueRow extends JPanel {
   public static final String[] COLS = {"Col 1", "Col 2"};
   private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(COLS, 0);
   private JTable table = new JTable(model);
   private JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);
   private JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);

   public UniqueRow() {
      add(new JScrollPane(table));
      add(textField1);
      add(textField2);
      ButtonAction action = new ButtonAction("Add Data");
      textField1.addActionListener(action);
      textField2.addActionListener(action);
      add(new JButton(action));
   }

   private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ButtonAction(String name) {
         super(name);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         // get text from JTextField
         String text1 = textField1.getText();
         String text2 = textField2.getText();

         // create a data row with it. Can use Vector if desired
         Object[] row = {text1, text2};

         // and add row to JTable
         model.addRow(row);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      UniqueRow mainPanel = new UniqueRow();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("UniqueRow");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```